# Check if cell value exists in excel sheet, then get the values of the bottom cells and add it

Tags: vba, excel

I have different defined category (Column A) in a sheet and these categories are spread across entire data sheet(F3:I14).

I want to add value for each category (a, b, c, d, e, f) from cell F3:I14 which is written below it in column Assigned (Column C).

For example:
For category a, add all numbers from cell F3:I14 which is written below a in cell C2.

[image]

I tried VLOOKUP formula but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a formula answer use this array formula:

```
=SUM(IF($F$3:$I$14=A2,$F$4:$I$15))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done properly then excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I upvoted Scott Craner's answer as I think it's the best, cleanest solution. But as you tagged this question with 'VBA', I thought I'd give a pure-programming solution to it with VBA, as well. If nothing else, it illustrates how powerfully simple a good formula like Scott's is!

```
Sub SumCategories()
    Const startColumn As Integer = 6 'F
    Const endColumn As Integer = 9 'I
    Const startRow As Integer = 3
    Const endRow As Integer = 14

    Const categoryColumn As Integer = 1 'A
    Const assignedColumn As Integer = 3 'C
    Dim categoryRow As Integer
    categoryRow = 2

    Dim categoryTotalAssigned As Integer
    categoryTotalAssigned = 0

    Dim currentCategory As String
    currentCategory = ActiveSheet.Cells(categoryRow, categoryColumn)

    While Not currentCategory = ""
        'Loop through all data to sum totals
        For c = startColumn To endColumn
            For r = startRow To endRow Step 2 'Look in every other row
                If ActiveSheet.Cells(r, c) = currentCategory Then
                    categoryTotalAssigned = categoryTotalAssigned + ActiveSheet.Cells(r + 1, c)
                End If
            Next r
        Next c

        'Write total for category
        ActiveSheet.Cells(categoryRow, assignedColumn) = categoryTotalAssigned

        'Move to next row
        categoryRow = categoryRow + 1

        'Reset total for next category
        categoryTotalAssigned = 0

        'Get next category
        currentCategory = ActiveSheet.Cells(categoryRow, categoryColumn)
    Wend
End Sub
```

[image: Result of VBA Script]